# $\Gamma(2)$ and $\Gamma_0(4)$ are conjugate

Tags: group-theory, modular-forms

Show that the groups $\Gamma(2)$ and $\Gamma_0(4)$ are conjugate to each other in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, where $\Gamma(2)$ and $\Gamma_0(4)$ is [congruence subgroups of the modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup#Congruence_subgroups_of_the_modular_group)

Is it the standard statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Both groups have index $6$ in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and they are conjugate by $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$. For details see the classification of the conjugacy classes of the genus zero congruence subgroups of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with no elliptic elements by Sebbar [here](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/asebbar/publi/duke.pdf), Section $7$, in particualr page $388$.

Comment: Dear Dietrich, is it true that each of this group have no elements of finite order except −1 ?

Comment: Yes, $\Gamma(N)$ has no nontrivial elements of finite order for $N\ge 3$, and only $-1$ for $N=2$. I fixed the link above, by the way.